# Angular Xeditable Grid with Typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [Angular Xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row) Grid.Could you tell me how to use `Typeahead` with it ? I have tried as shown below.But it is not working :( Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
  <span editable-text="user.status" e-name="status" e-form="rowform" 
        e-typeahead="s as s.text for s in statuses | filter:$viewValue">
          {{ showStatus(user) }}
 </span>
```

**Update :** When user clicks the Edit button, it shows the `id` of the property.But it should be the `text`.How can I get rid of this ?

Here is the Updated fiddle with the latest version of the Xeditable [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/xo5c92e7/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/8103rdkn/45/) working.

I added typeahead-input-formatter: `e-typeahead-input-formatter="formatStatus($model)"` and typeahead-on-select `e-typeahead-on-select="onSelectedCallback($item, $model, $label)"` to your typeahead.

I also updated the saveUser function.

**html**

```
 <span editable-text="user.status" e-name="status" e-form="rowform" 
        e-uib-typeahead="s as s.text for s in statuses | filter:$viewValue" 
        e-typeahead-input-formatter="formatStatus($model)"
        e-typeahead-on-select="onSelectedCallback($item, $model, $label)" >
          {{ showStatus(user) }}
  </span>
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.showStatus = function(user) {
        if (user.status && user.status.text) {
          return user.status.text;
        }

        var selected = [];
        if (user.status) {
          selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {value: user.status});
        }
        return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
      };

 $scope.formatStatus = function(status) {
    var displayText;
    angular.forEach($scope.statuses, function(data) {
      if (data.value === status || data.value === status.value) {
        displayText = data.text;
        return;
      }
    });

    return displayText ? displayText : status;
  };

  $scope.onSelectedCallback = function ($item, $model, $label, $event) {
          $model.status = $item.value;
    };
```